# How to have QGIS show the number of points that overlay the raster polygon?

Tags: qgis

I have a number of single-value raster layers defining a area mask and a point layer pulled from PostGIS. Is there a way to have Quantum GIS show me the number of points that overlay the raster polygon? Or is my only option to convert the raster to a vector, pull into the database, and run a query against it?

Comment: Are the rasters irregularly shaped? If they are simple boxes/rectangles you could just pull the coordinates of a couple corners and perform a query against the point coordinates to determine if they fall inside.

Comment: They're very irregularly shaped. Something similar to http://www.softwright.com/tap5covmap1.jpg, with the red raster polygon being a superset of the green raster polygon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a plug-in called `Point Samping Tool`

You can use it to harvest the raster values for each point, and then short them as you wish